# Speeding up postgres / Redshift queries

Tags: amazon-redshift, query-optimization

I have been given a requirement to query 8(+) different Redshift tables from a Lambda function and return some of the fields where email = provided email address.

Current implementation is a JDBC connection using Spring Data JDBC :

```
@Query("select * from
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyA) companyA 
 natural full join
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyB) companyB 
 natural full join
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyC) companyC 
 natural full join
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyD) companyD 
 natural full join
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyE) companyE 
 natural full join
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyF) companyF 
 natural full join
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyG) companyG 
 natural full join
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyH) companyH 
 where email = :emailId;")
public List<Contact> getContactSortByDate(String emailId);
```

The problem with this approach is that each of these tables are quite large and so the query can take 45+ seconds. To make it worse, I will eventually need to implement a one to many join on "accountid" to 8 account tables to grab some fields there.

And... my boss wants all of this to happen in less than 5 seconds... I don't think that will be possible, but I wanted to know if there were things I can do to speed this search up as much as possible?

Questions:

- is there a way to make this query faster?
- If I am able to switch to using the Redshift client from inside the VPC instead of a JDBC connection, is there still any hope of getting below (or anywhere near) 5 seconds?

EDIT:
As requested, here is the *Updated* results of '''EXPLAIN```:

```
XN Subquery Scan alltables  (cost=35.45..142252362.72 rows=35 width=520)
  ->  XN Append  (cost=35.45..142252362.37 rows=35 width=1440)
        ->  XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=35.45..67200090.91 rows=11 width=1440)
              ->  XN Hash Join DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=35.45..67200090.80 rows=11 width=1440)
                    Hash Cond: (("outer".id)::text = ("inner".accountid)::text)
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on companyA_accounts acc  (cost=0.00..4.91 rows=491 width=816)
                    ->  XN Hash  (cost=35.43..35.43 rows=10 width=663)
                          ->  XN Seq Scan on companyA usr  (cost=0.00..35.43 rows=10 width=663)
                                Filter: ((email)::text = 'foobybar@barfoo.com'::text)
        ->  XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=41.85..41600165.37 rows=11 width=943)
              ->  XN Hash Join DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=41.85..41600165.26 rows=11 width=943)
                    Hash Cond: (("outer".id)::text = ("inner".accountid)::text)
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on companyB_accounts acc  (cost=0.00..10.96 rows=1096 width=550)
                    ->  XN Hash  (cost=41.83..41.83 rows=10 width=406)
                          ->  XN Seq Scan on companyB usr  (cost=0.00..41.83 rows=10 width=406)
                                Filter: ((email)::text = 'foobybar@barfoo.com'::text)
        ->  XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 3"  (cost=512.54..6241501.45 rows=2 width=1374)
              ->  XN Hash Join DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=512.54..6241501.43 rows=2 width=1374)
                    Hash Cond: (("outer".id)::text = ("inner".accountid)::text)
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on companyC_accounts acc  (cost=0.00..439.50 rows=43950 width=771)
                    ->  XN Hash  (cost=512.54..512.54 rows=1 width=614)
                          ->  XN Seq Scan on companyC usr  (cost=0.00..512.54 rows=1 width=614)
                                Filter: ((email)::text = 'foobybar@barfoo.com'::text)
        ->  XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 4"  (cost=2178.78..4403808.58 rows=3 width=985)
              ->  XN Hash Join DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=2178.78..4403808.55 rows=3 width=985)
                    Hash Cond: (("outer".id)::text = ("inner".accountid)::text)
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on companyD_accounts acc  (cost=0.00..501.46 rows=50146 width=809)
                    ->  XN Hash  (cost=2178.78..2178.78 rows=2 width=212)
                          ->  XN Seq Scan on companyD usr  (cost=0.00..2178.78 rows=2 width=212)
                                Filter: (((email)::text = 'foobybar@barfoo.com'::text) AND (accountid IS NOT NULL))
        ->  XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 5"  (cost=3534.94..4244248.75 rows=2 width=511)
              ->  XN Hash Join DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=3534.94..4244248.73 rows=2 width=511)
                    Hash Cond: (("outer".id)::text = ("inner".accountid)::text)
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on companyE_accounts acc  (cost=0.00..219.62 rows=21962 width=347)
                    ->  XN Hash  (cost=3534.94..3534.94 rows=2 width=203)
                          ->  XN Seq Scan on companyE usr  (cost=0.00..3534.94 rows=2 width=203)
                                Filter: (((email)::text = 'foobybar@barfoo.com'::text) AND (accountid IS NOT NULL))
        ->  XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 6"  (cost=810.77..1921107.33 rows=1 width=1175)
              ->  XN Hash Join DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=810.77..1921107.32 rows=1 width=1175)
                    Hash Cond: (("outer".id)::text = ("inner".accountid)::text)
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on companyF_accounts acc  (cost=0.00..131.80 rows=13180 width=1030)
                    ->  XN Hash  (cost=810.76..810.76 rows=1 width=184)
                          ->  XN Seq Scan on companyF usr  (cost=0.00..810.76 rows=1 width=184)
                                Filter: ((email)::text = 'foobybar@barfoo.com'::text)
        ->  XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 7"  (cost=705.19..9200982.48 rows=3 width=1204)
              ->  XN Hash Join DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=705.19..9200982.45 rows=3 width=1204)
                    Hash Cond: (("outer".id)::text = ("inner".accountid)::text)
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on companyG_accounts acc  (cost=0.00..85.30 rows=8530 width=790)
                    ->  XN Hash  (cost=705.19..705.19 rows=2 width=449)
                          ->  XN Seq Scan on companyG usr  (cost=0.00..705.19 rows=2 width=449)
                                Filter: ((email)::text = 'foobybar@barfoo.com'::text)
        ->  XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 8"  (cost=420.21..7440457.49 rows=2 width=1135)
              ->  XN Hash Join DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=420.21..7440457.47 rows=2 width=1135)
                    Hash Cond: (("outer".id)::text = ("inner".accountid)::text)
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on companyH_accounts acc  (cost=0.00..11.46 rows=1146 width=784)
                    ->  XN Hash  (cost=420.20..420.20 rows=2 width=362)
                          ->  XN Seq Scan on companyH usr  (cost=0.00..420.20 rows=2 width=362)
                                Filter: ((email)::text = 'foobybar@barfoo.com'::text)
```

**Solution:**
As [O.Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75465921/12380096) pointed out, 'UNION ALL' sped it up by quite a bit! I still have a bunch of joins, but brought the time down by a lot. Here is the final solution:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
     SELECT usr.product_name, acc.product_loc, acc.phone, usr.email, usr.firstname, usr.lastname, usr.accountid,  
       FROM companyA usr
         JOIN companyA_accounts acc ON usr.accountid = acc.id
     UNION ALL 
    SELECT usr.product_name, acc.product_loc, acc.phone, usr.email, usr.firstname, usr.lastname, usr.accountid,  
      FROM companyB usr
         JOIN companyB_accounts acc ON usr.accountid = acc.id
     /* UNION ALL SELECT repeated for the rest of the tables */
  ) alltables
 WHERE alltables.email =  :emailId;
```

I am still open to information on best practices / efficiency if switching to RedshiftClient though!

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) already asked here. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/323561

Comment: Won't there be lots of duplicates with that query? Or is the e-mail a unique key?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe email is not a unique key as some customers may have an account with multiple companies. Also, For some reason, there are sometimes multiple accounts within the same company.  So yes, some duplicates, but I need those and the most I have founds so far was like 7 entries total.

Comment: Please edit the question and add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this query, using an ordinary UNION ALL rather than all those JOINs?

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM (
     SELECT product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
       FROM companyA
     UNION ALL 
    SELECT product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
      FROM companyB
     /* UNION ALL SELECT repeated for the rest of the tables */
  ) alltables
  JOIN some_other_table ON alltables.accountid = some_other_table.accountid
 WHERE alltables.email =  :emailId;
```

A query like this can exploit any indexes on the `email` columns of any tables that have them.

And, as my example shows you can do the joins with fairly clean SQL.

Comment: Thank you! That sped things up quite a bit! I still have to do a join on each select because it is ```JOIN companyA_accounts on companyA.accountid = companyA_accounts.id``` but even with all those joins it has brought it down to 30 secs at the most with most queries between 0 and 10secs!  Thanks again!

Comment: Still seems like a lot of time if there is proper indexing,  @AylaWinters: Could you update the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for your latest solution based on this answer?  (Does RedShift support `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE, COSTS)` ?)

Comment: @deroby I updated the Explain. It does not look like RDS has the others available.

Comment: @AylaWinters From what I understand from the plan it looks like the system has to scan the (entire) table to find the relevant records. Adding an index on each `companyX` table for the combination `email, accountId` might help out quite a bit .